# Xamarin UI Test connection reset by peer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I've been having lots of trouble running Xamarin UITest on iOS 11+ devices.

```
      ...
      return ConfigureApp
                .iOS
                .Debug()
                .InstalledApp("com.my.packageidentifier")
                .StartApp(AppDataMode.Clear);
      ...
```

gives the error...

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : An error occurred while sending the request.
 ----> System.IO.IOException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
 ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Connection reset by peer
```

and......

```
System.Exception : IDE failed to deploy app: Build failed
```

My dev environment is pretty up to date...

Xamarin.UITest (3.0.2)
Xamarin.iOS (12.14.0.110)

Visual Studio 2019 (Mac)

Has anyone run into these errors for iOS 11.x devices and know how to resolve them?

Here is the stacktrace from the first error, which is more common....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Updating xamarin UI test package after updating your visual studio might resolve your problem. 
see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.UITest/